# Trigger After Delete Not working

Tags: mysql

Here is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER `agent_maintenance` AFTER DELETE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO deleted_agents (agent_id, fullname, email, mobile_no, deleted) 
SELECT user_id, fullname, email, mobile_no, NOW() FROM user_profiles WHERE user_id = OLD.id;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Apparently nothing got inserted to table deleted_agents
But when i change the event to `BEFORE DELETE` it work just fine.
Anyone know what is wrong?

**EDITED**
Yes there is foreign key constraint inside table user_profiles.
Basically when a row from table `user` got deleted, it will delete a coresponding row on table `user_profiles`.

So i make a wrong assumption that a trigger would be executed first before any foreign key constraint action

The best way to do this is to use `AFTER DELETE` trigger on table user_profiles itself.
Unfortunately **mysql dosent activate the trigger on foreign key constraint**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that since the row has been deleted a cascading delete trigger on the user_profiles table has executed and the WHERE clause cannot find the user_id?

Comment: `OLD.column` is use to access value from deleted row

Comment: Are there other triggers that possibly cascade and delete on user_profiles after deleting on users such that user_id wouldn't be found in user profiles?

Comment: @actkatiemacias you should update your answer.  The `OLD`.`id` is still valid in an `AFTER DELETE` trigger but I suspect you hit the nail on (or close to) the head with your comment... there's probably an `ON DELETE CASCADE` on a foreign key on user_profiles that references users(id), causing that row to disappear before the `AFTER` trigger fires.